# How to insert images according to creation date with google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm looking to inesrt image files into google slides according to the date they were created. I have the following code, which sequentually
inserts images to googles slides from a drive folder:

```
function makeSlides() {
  
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(slideID);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var contents = folder.getFiles()
  
  var file;
  var i = 1;
  
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    
    var file = contents.next();
  
    data = file.getId(); 
    
    // insert above image
    
    var image = DriveApp.getFileById(data);
    var slide = presentation.getSlides()[i];
    var image = slide.insertImage(image);
    slide = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);    
    i++;
 
  }

}
```

I would like to alter it so that the images are added by the date they were created (either newest or oldest). Any help received will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the image files from the specific folder.
- You want to put the retrieved images to Google Slides in order of the created date of the file.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

When the method of "Files: list" in Drive API is used, the file list can be retrieved in order of the created date. This is used for the modification.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function makeSlides() {
  var slideID = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.
  var folderID = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.

  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(slideID);
  var files = Drive.Files.list({orderBy: "createdDate asc", q: `'${folderID}' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType contains 'image'`, fields: "items(id)"}).items;
  files.forEach(({id}, i) => {
    var image = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    var slide = presentation.getSlides()[i];
    var image = slide.insertImage(image);
    slide = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the file list is retrieved from the specific folder in order of the created date of the file. In this case, `orderBy: "createdDate asc"` is used. This mean that the 1st image is the oldest image. When you want to use the order that the 1st image is the newest image, please modify to `orderBy: "createdDate desc"`.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tanaike, this does exactly what I want.

Comment: @sp2 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I'm finding the above code is not able to load in files from a shared google drive (the code gives no error, it just doesn't load anything). I can only load images from my personal drive - would you have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @sp2 About your additional question, in that case, please modify ``var files = Drive.Files.list({orderBy: "createdDate asc", q: `'${folderID}' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType contains 'image'`, fields: "items(id)"}).items;`` to ``var files = Drive.Files.list({orderBy: "createdDate asc", q: `'${folderID}' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType contains 'image'`, fields: "items(id)", corpora: "allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true}).items;``. By this, the files in the shared Drive can be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, this works. I have been trying to modify the `orderBy` parameter to sort files by the order `'name'` and `'name_natural'` etc. as outline [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), but it gives an error. Why can't `orderBy` accept these parameters in this way?

Comment: @sp2 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your all questions. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. Can I ask you about the detail of your 3rd question?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, that is perfectly understandable, no need to apologise. Basically, I was asking how can I add images in alphabetical order? I wanted to use `orderBy : name` or `orderBy : name_natural` in your code instead of `orderBy : createdDate`, as outlined in the link I shared, but it does not work, was just wondering why.

Comment: @sp2 Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your 2nd question, for example, in my answer, when the file list is retrieved in order of `createdDate`, I used `createdDate asc` as the value. And in this case, when you want to sort the file list by the filename, how about using `orderBy: "title asc"`? If this was not the direct solution of your 2nd question, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes, this works and does what I want. Just wondering, do you have a link for where these fields (e.g. `title` etc.) are given? I tried googling for it but could not find anything, there may be other fields that are useful to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @sp2 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your additional question was also resolved. About the document of "title" of fields, you can see it at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files).

Answer (score 1):

If you want them in specific order just [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them before adding.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link